# Java printf (String, Val, String)

Tags: java, printf

This is probably really simple, but I've been stuck on this for a while.

I am trying to output a **String** and then a **double** with two decimals followed by another **string** and here's is my code.

`System.out.printf("Cost: %.2f%n" , hourCost , "/hour");`

Gives output:

`Cost: 8.00`

What I would like to have:

`Cost: 8.00/hour`

I am not sure whether I can have two strings and a value between them when using printf.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to provide the second string as a separate argument unless it's a variable; in general, the other answers are correct, of course, but in your specific example you may use:

```
System.out.printf("Cost: %.2f/hour%n", hourCost);
```

Comment: You're missing the `%n` from the original in the question. Unless of course you think the `%n` was intended to be a `%s`, but then you should say so in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

For your desired output, you need to add an additional format *parameter*. Change

```
System.out.printf("Cost: %.2f%n" , hourCost , "/hour");
```

to add a `%s` for the next `String` argument. Like,

```
System.out.printf("Cost: %.2f%s%n" , hourCost , "/hour");
```

Comment: I feel like `"Cost: %.2f/hour%n"` is a better solution

Comment: @tkausl In that case, you should post it as an answer, and maybe earn some upvotes.

Answer (score -3):

Try using below code snippet

```
System.out.printf("Cost: %.2f%s" , hourCost ,  "/hour");
```